# tailwind can't spill when trying to fit menu to screen

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

full snippet: https://jsfiddle.net/3Lapnszc/1/

trying to fit this part to screen, the left nav menu

```html
  <main class="flex flex-grow w-full h-screen">
  <aside class="w-80 h-screen bg-gray shadow-md w-full hidden sm:block">
    <div class="flex flex-grow flex-col justify-between h-full p-4 bg-gray-800">
        <div class="text-sm">
          <div class="bg-gray-900 text-white p-2 rounded mt-2 cursor-pointer hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-blue-300">Backlog</div>
          <div class="bg-gray-700 text-blue-300 p-2 rounded mt-2 cursor-pointer">Board</div>
          <div class="bg-gray-900 flex justify-between items-center text-white p-2 rounded mt-2 cursor-pointer hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-blue-300">
            <span>Reports</span>
            <span class="w-4 h-4 bg-blue-600 rounded-full text-white text-center font-normal text-xs">5</span>
          </div>
          <div class="bg-gray-900 text-white p-2 rounded mt-2 cursor-pointer hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-blue-300">Releases</div>
          <div class="bg-gray-900 text-white p-2 rounded mt-2 cursor-pointer hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-blue-300">Components</div>
          <div class="bg-gray-900 text-white p-2 rounded mt-2 cursor-pointer hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-blue-300">Repository</div>
        </div>

        <div class="flex p-3 text-white bg-red-500 rounded cursor-pointer text-center text-sm">
          <button class="rounded inline-flex items-center">
            <svg class="w-4 h-4 mr-2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor"><path fillRule="evenodd" d="M3 3a1 1 0 00-1 1v12a1 1 0 102 0V4a1 1 0 00-1-1zm10.293 9.293a1 1 0 001.414 1.414l3-3a1 1 0 000-1.414l-3-3a1 1 0 10-1.414 1.414L14.586 9H7a1 1 0 100 2h7.586l-1.293 1.293z" clipRule="evenodd" /></svg>
            <span class="font-semibold">Logout</span>
          </button>
        </div>
    </div>
  </aside>

  <section class="w-full p-4">
    <div class="w-full h-64 border-dashed border-4 p-4 text-md">Dashboard</div>
    </section>

  </main>
```

I tried grow, full, flex-grow, etc.
Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `h-screen` from `<aside>` element

and then add this to preceding `main` element:

```
<main class="flex flex-grow w-full" style="height: calc(100vh - 64px);">
```

As you can see, it's not tailwind way to do, but it basically set height of element to maximum screen height **minus** header height.
You could apply this to your css an/or media query css as well.